# The multi-part identifier error with table alias

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a query with a join to a linked server and am getting the error

> The multi-part identifier "tbl_CUA_Visitation_Report_Line.acct_trip_end_date" could not be bound.

I have aliased the tables in the query below:

```
  SELECT r.visitation_report_id 
  FROM [dbo].[tbl_CUA_Visitation_Report] as r
  inner join [SERVER\INSTANCE].[DATABASE].[dbo].[tbl_CUA_Visitation_Report_Line] as l
  on r.visitation_report_id = l.visitation_report_id
```

The field in the error is present in the table (and only that table), I cannot figure out what the problem is. Most of the messages I have seen about the multi-part error was because a table was not aliased with a linked server.

Both databases are 2008 R2 (one at SP1 the other at SP2).

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to add that I have no problem if I run (select * from [SERVER\INSTANCE].[DATABASE].[dbo].[tbl_CUA_Visitation_Report_Line])

Comment: This error does not seem to come from the code you posted. That column isn't even mentioned, and since both tables have the useless prefix `tbl_`, I hope they're not views.

Comment: No, they are not views, but using an out dated naming convention. The error has stuck as to what the issue might be.

Comment: Okay, I still don't see how it is even remotely possible that *that* error message came from *that* query...

Comment: Are you sure that this the exact query you're running?

Answer (score 0):

we just had this problem here. To solve it by the fastest way, remove all the brackets. Please let me know if that works for you.